# Pig Programming with Tuples

Tags: apache-pig

How do I return a tuple from a UDF?

I know how to return a String from UDF.

Can someone explain to me how to return a Tuple from a UDF with a simple example?

Answer (score 2):

Just replace string with tuple like below..

```
public class YourUdf extends EvalFunc<Tuple> {

    public Tuple exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {

             DefaultTuple dt = new DefaultTuple();//creating tuple object

            //using tuple object you can add the values

                              //your code here;

             return dt;
    }    

}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Python UDF it's your @outputSchema that defines you is that it is a tuple or String. exemple :

```
@outputSchema("record: {(Id, name, age)}")
```